Can't delete entity with EmbeddableId in Spring JPA
I'm trying to delete an entity with a composite primary key whose constituents are other 2 entities from a database (many to many relationship, code below). The primary keys of these entities are ids of type Long and I try to delete exactly by these ids (the code is again below) without a native request, but in response I get the following exception:
jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call.
As I understand it, there is no suitable method for such removal, although, as for me, the name of the method is constructed correctly.
And in this regard, I have a question - is it possible in my case to carry out the deletion by delegating the construction of the request to Spring JPA?
Repository:
@Repository
public interface ServiceOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<ServiceOrder, ServiceOrderPk> {

    List<ServiceOrder> findAllByPkOrderId(Long id);

    void deleteByPkOrderIdAndPkServiceId(Long orderId, Long serviceId);
}

P.S. findAllByPkOrderId is working.
Order entity class:
// annotations skipped
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(
            targetEntity = Client.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Client client;

    @Column(name = "registration_date")
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

    @Column(name = "appointment_date")
    private LocalDateTime appointmentDate;

    @Column(name = "execution_date")
    private LocalDateTime executionDate;
}

Service entity class:
// annotations skipped also 
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
}

Service-Order primary key:
// you know what I want to write
public class ServiceOrderPk implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(
            targetEntity = Order.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne(
            targetEntity = Service.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")
    private Service service;

}

Service-Order entity:
// ...
public class ServiceOrder {

    @EmbeddedId
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private ServiceOrderPk pk;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "percent_discount")
    private Long percentDiscount;

}

And additionally: does it make sense to write fetch = FetchType.LAZY not over a collection?

The jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException typically occurs when we’re trying to perform a database operation that modifies the database without a transaction.
Check where you are calling deleteByPkOrderIdAndPkServiceId, you should have an active transaction open.
Note that the findAllByPkOrderId might work even if you don't declare the transaction in JPA because read-only transactions are many times created automatically by the JDBC driver, depends on the driver. But still it is a bad practice to rely on this, better to explicitly declare the read-only transaction there too, if you don't have it already.

Yes thank you.
I already searched the Internet about this and solved my problem and the @Transactional annotation was part of the solution. I'll write about the rest in my own answer to this question as soon as I stop being lazy, if you're interested.
